# Retrieving values from jsp without using pojo variables

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

We can get the values of a submitted form in a jsp page in controller using `request.getParamenter(xxxx)`,by using commandName or by using hidden fields.

is there any other way to get values from a form of jsp in a controller?

Comment: Do you still have any questions after reading the answers?

Comment: Yes..it was ok when we go with Spring MVC..what about when we go with Servlets..i mean retrieving values in servlets..do we have same annotations like that what we have in spring..???

Comment: Once you move away from Spring MVC, meaning the dispatchers and servlets, you will lose the databinding functionality provided by Spring.  Having worked with Spring MVC I would much rather use the framework than a straight J2EE stack.

Answer (score 2):

Spring provides several ways of databinding parameters in your request to actual objects in Java.  Most of the databinding is specified using annotated methods or by annotating paramters within methods.

**Lets consider the following form:**

```
<form>
  <input name="firstName"/>
  <input name="lastName"/>
  <input name="age"/>
</form>
```

In a Spring controller the request parameters can be retreived in several ways.

**@RequestParam**  [Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

```
@RequestMapping("/someurl)
public String processForm(@RequestParam("firstName") String  firstName, 
   @RequestParam("lastName") String  lastName, 
       @RequestParam("age") String  int,) {
 .....
}
```

If our request parameters are modeled in a class `Person.java` we can use another technique, `@ModelAttribute`.

**Person.java**

```
public class Person(){
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   int age;

   //Constructors and Accessors implied.
}
```

**@ModelAttribute**  [Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someUrl")
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute Person person) {
   //person parameter will be bound to request parameters using field/param name matching.
}
```

These are two of the most commonly used methods Spring uses to provide databinding.  Read up on others in the [Spring MVC Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String myMethod(@RequestParam("myParamOne") String myParamOne) {
 //do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly map fields to controller method by annotation `@RequestParam` or you can directly bind object using `@ModelAttribute`.

```
public ModelAndView method(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "id") Long id) {
}

public ModelAndView method(@ModelAttribute("pojo") POJO pojo, BindingResult results) {
}
```